# Stripping characters from a Bash variable (2)

Tags: bash

I have a small script where I need to take off everything from the first period ('.').

I use `${i%.*}`:

```
#!/bin/bash
today=$(date +"%Y%m%d")
limdir="/some/dir/"

cd $limdir  || exit
  for i in *Limit*${today}.csv
      do
      echo $i 
      echo /var/tmp/casper/${i%.*}
      done
```

Which takes off everything from the last period.

```
casper1LimitChanges.20180813.csv
/var/tmp/bin/script/xenon/casper1LimitChanges.20180813

casper1LimitSnapshot.20180813.csv
/var/tmp/bin/script/xenon/casper1LimitSnapshot.20180813
```

I want everything from the first period. The files need to look like this:

```
casper1LimitChanges.20180813.csv
/var/tmp/bin/script/xenon/casper1LimitChanges

casper1LimitSnapshot.20180813.csv
/var/tmp/bin/script/xenon/casper1LimitSnapshot
```

Comment: use `${i%%.*}` instead of `${i%.*}` -- doubling the % means greedy matching. Same would apply for `${i##*.}` and `${i#*.}`

Comment: Also, get into the habit of double-quoting your variables: `for i in *Limit*"$today".csv` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this inside the loop:

```
echo $i 
echo /var/tmp/casper/$i |cut -d\. -f1
```